# Call a function with several properties of an object

Tags: matlab, function, oop, properties

For (MEX) function calls it would be really nice to pass several properties of one object at once. Instead of `foo(myObj.propA, myObj.propB)` I want something like `foo(myObj.[propA,propB]`.

**Is this even possible?**

With structs it is possible to use the [`getfield()`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html.) function to get the data from more than one field, e.g.:

```
getfield(myStruct, {index}, {'fieldA', 'fieldB'})
```

But unfortunately, the following attempt to get more than one property from an object results in an error (Index exceeds matrix dimensions):

```
getfield(myObj, {index}, {'propA', 'propB'})
```

Maybe the only possibility is to write a function which returns several output arguments:

```
[varargout] = getProps(object,propnames)

for p=1:numel(propnames)
    varargout{p} = object.(propnames{p});
end
```

But if I call another function with that function as input, e.g. `sum(getProps(myObj,propnames))` only the first output argument of `getProps` is passed and I fall into despair. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

For an object, you'd use `get`, not `getfield` (or dynamic access in a loop like you showed).

```
>> h = figure;
>> get(h,{'Position','Renderer'})
ans = 
    [1x4 double]    'opengl'
```

This doesn't work for all objects, but for MATLAB graphics objects it does work.  To deal with any class, you can use your function, but with a custom cell output instead of `varargout`:

```
function C = getProps(object,propnames)

for p = 1:numel(propnames),
    C{p} = object.(propnames{p});
end
```

Then inside whatever function you write, you can get a comma-separated list of all properties with `C{:}`, which will be suitable for a function that expects each property name input as a separate argument (e.g. `C = getProps(myObj,propnames); x = myFun(h,C{:})`.

Comment: Maybe my Matlab R2011b is too old, but the inputs are not really given separatedly to the function. For example with an object with property values `A=1` and `B=3`: 
`C = getProps(obj,{'A' 'B'})` gives `C =[1] [3]` and `C{:}`returns the comma-separated list `ans = 1; ans = 3` but sum(C{:}) returns `ans = 1`.

Comment: @JaBe Then doing `myfun(C{:})` will give `myfun` two inputs.  When you do `sum(C{:})` this is equivalent to `sum(1,3)`, which computes the sum over the **third dimension**, not the sum of the two numbers. You would need to concatenate to get a signle array: `[C{:}]`.

Comment: @JaBe If this gave you the information you needed for this question, please accept.  Thanks!  :)